# axios has no exported member 'CancelToken'

Tags: typescript, axios

I am migrating a JavaScript codebase to TypeScript.
In many source files I had:

```
import {CancelToken} from 'axios';
```

... and cancellation worked perfectly. Upon migrating to TypeScript I am getting:

```
TS2305: Module '"./some/path/node_modules/axios/index.js"' has no exported member 'CancelToken'.
```

Upon investigating, I see that file `node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js` (imported from `axios/index.js`) does indeed contain a named member `CancelToken`:

```
axios.CancelToken = require('./cancel/CancelToken');
...
module.exports = axios;
```

(and how could it be differntly since the Javascript version of the code worked).
Weirdly, though, the exact same name is used for an interface type (found in `node_modules/axios/lib/index.t.ds`):

```
export interface CancelToken {
  promise: Promise<Cancel>;
  reason?: Cancel;
 throwIfRequested(): void;
```

}

My questions are:

1. how do I properly address or, failing that, get around this error?
2. when, in my code, I do `import {CancelToken} from 'axios'` am I importing the object from `axios/index.js` or the interface from `axios/index.d.ts`? (I am assuming the former). Is there no clash / how can I make it unambiguous ?

## update

Upon further experimenting I tried:

```
import {CancelToken} from './some/path/node_modules/axios/index.js';
```

... which got me a different message:

```
TS2693: 'CancelToken' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

In my code I have:

```
const source = CancelToken.source();
```

... and it is for the above line that TypeScript is complaining that "[the] type [...] is being used as a value".

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
import axios from 'axios'

const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially ended up doing:

```
import CancelToken from './some/path/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel/CancelToken.js';
```

... which seems like a hack and I've no idea why it was necessary. A few days later I discovered a better way:

I set `"moduleResolution": "node"` in my `"compilerOptions"` structure in the `tsconfig.json` file and then used:

```
const {CancelToken} = require('axios');
```